# How can I add custom text to Shippo labels using batch API?

Tags: shippo

I need to add custom text to some of labels generated with [shippo batch API](https://goshippo.com/docs/batch/). How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by adding extra data to [batch shipment object](https://goshippo.com/docs/reference#batches-batch-shipments). There are [multiple keys](https://goshippo.com/docs/reference#shipments-extras) for extra map but we interested in "reference_1" and "reference_2". Here is example of kotlin code to create shipment with custom text on label:

```
val shipment = Shipment.createForBatch(fromAddress, toAddress, listOf(parcel))
val extraMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
extraMap["reference_1"] = "Line 1 of custom text"
extraMap["reference_2"] = "Line 2 of custom text"
shipment.extra = extraMap
```